# Interactive terminal solution for Emacs on Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell, term

I recently tried to move from over to Emacs but hit a brick wall while trying to setup a terminal. While `shell` and `eshell` work fine, they are not really interactive so you can't really run things such as `gdb` or `vim`. There's `term` and `ansi-term`, but from online research, it appears as though they don't work on Windows. I get `Spawning child process: Invalid argument` error whenever I try to run either of those.

I was hoping maybe to use [vterm](https://github.com/akermu/emacs-libvterm), except it's not available on Windows. Although, I did manage to compile it on MSYS2, but the MSYS2 version of Emacs has no GUI, only terminal.

Can anything be done?

Comment: Did you give `M-x term` a valid executable to run?

Comment: @phils Yes, I even tried changing the hardcoded terminal in `term.el`. The furthest I got was getting it to start, but it was completely unresponsive, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/43264208/5530486